# NSAttributedString setFont does not apply to emoji characters

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, emoji

I am using Nimbus `NIAttributedLabel` class to display text which sometimes contain emoji characters. I set the font size to `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]` but emoji characters seem to ignore that. With UILabel all characters are displayed correctly.

NIAttributedLabel internally calls

```
[self addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)fontRef range:range];
```

I suppose `NSAttributedString` has to switch to a different font when it sees emoji characters. Is there any trick to make sure it uses the same font size?

Comment: See
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559510/increase-the-font-size-of-emoji-characters-in-a-uitextview-in-ios-5-x
this may helps.